# My program stops after 1 iteration, while comparing two lists

Tags: python, list

I have a function which takes a main list, that has 3 lists inside, I want to take each list and relate it to another list of 3 elements. I want this to happen to the 3 lists inside of my main list.

I really dont understand why it only iterates once.
Note: if I delete the line 8, the code does the same, but I left it in there so my intention is noticed, which is a want an inner iteration to each list:

```
for item1 in range(3):# and execute this loop 3 times
```

Here is the code:

```
main_list =[["one","two","three"],["three","two","one"],["two","one","three"]]
comparison_list = ["element1","element2","element3"]

def correlator(list):
    count = -1
    for item in list:#I want to take each list
        try:
            for item1 in range(3):# and execute this loop 3 times
                count += 1
                print(f' {item[count]} is related to {comparison_list[count]}')

        except IndexError:
            pass

correlator(main_list)
```

The result is:

```
 one is related to element1
  two is related to element2
  three is related to element3
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
  one is related to element1
  two is related to element2
  three is related to element3

  three is related to element1
  two is related to element2
  oneis related to element3

  two is related to element1
  one is related to element2
  three is related to element3
```

Comment: You should reset `count` in your `for item in list...` loop

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, By setting it to 0 after the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the error seems to be that you are not resetting the counter, and hence get the `index out of range` error.
Not sure why you need a `try`/`except` clause here. For this, the following list comprehension suffices:

```
[f'{i} is related to {j}' for l in main_list for i,j in zip(l,comparison_list)]

['one is related to element1',
 'two is related to element2',
 'three is related to element3',
 'three is related to element1',
 'two is related to element2',
 'one is related to element3',
 'two is related to element1',
 'one is related to element2',
 'three is related to element3']
```

---

Which is equivalent to (simply printing out the strings here):

```
for l in main_list:
    for i,j in zip(l,comparison_list):
        print(f'{i} is related to {j}')
```

Comment: Didnt knew the zip() function existed, thanks a lot.